# What is a Java&microservice way to handle, test and verify SQL requests send with JDBC on Database side?

Tags: java, database, jdbc, integration-testing, microservices

We have a JDBC connection to some external DB, which can not be easily dumped and deployed somewhere on our side, since it is a secret; we just know that several our SQL requests sent via jdbc connection are working for it; now we need an integration test emulating the real connection to the external machine, not the mock; however, we'd like to introduce some kind of docker container with the java code accepting the jdbc connection in the manner the real db does it; then just to parse the incoming requests and verify the extracted data; the particular jdbc driver on the jdbc client side is not the problem; the problem is that I can't fugure out is there the api of any Java-written databases to accept the incoming SQL request as an event for this kind of application?

The integration test needing is is due to microservice architecture; we prever the integration tests with real network connections than mocks.

Comment: What are you trying to test? Correctness of SQL queries generated by your code could be tested with unit tests for your DAO.
If you need to test network connectivity and parsing of query results you could start HSQLDB server and prepopulate it with some relevant data and configure your application to connect to that HSQLDB server.

Comment: I'd like to extract data sent with sql requests as the only output of the system (that's for integration test) and verify against data put to the input of the system. between the input and the output we have the complicated data pipleine and the insert requests are the only output of this complicated system. but conventional way "let the system put entries to db and then read them" is not avalable to us since we have no ideda about the db and know few valid sql requests that db structure. so we need some tool/llibrary just accepting the requests and allowing to handle and parse them